# HTML5 popcornjs video have seconds offset/delay in android smartphones/tablets

Tags: android, html, video, html5-video, popcornjs

I'm developing a interactive `HTML5` video with `HTML` elements over it. I'm using the javascript library popcornjs to jump to specific seconds, make loops in the video and show and hide html elements in some seconds.

It is working fine in desktop browsers but when I try it in android smartphones or tablets there are a delay or offset in the seconds of the video.

**For example**:

I have a loop between seconds 8 and 12 of the video and it change to 7 and 11 in mobile.

I'm using the function `currentTime()` of `popcornjs`. The video format that I'm using is **mp4**.

What could it be the problem?

EDIT: Analyzing deeply the problem it seems that the function `currentTime()` works fine, this goes to the correct second but immediately the player goes to a wrong second.

**For example**:

```html
popcorn.currentTime(8);
popcorn.pause();
```

In this code, `currentTime()` goes to second 8 and pause correctly but if I play the video, it immediately go to the second 7.

If I use `currentTime()` with the second 9, 10, 11 or 12, it still goes to second 7. With the parameter 13 it goes correctly to the second 13.

It seems there is allways a range of seconds which go to the same second using `currentTime()`.

Comment: Any progress on this problem? We're experiencing the same issue...